# Can you receive Events in a secondary thread in Delphi XE?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, events

I would like to have three threads in a sample application.
Thread #1 (Main Thread) - User Interface/GUI
Thread #2 - Tied to a serial port device receiving data via events passing to a data queue.
Thread #3 - Activated when a queue entry is made, process data node, frees data object.

The goal is to
a) Prevent the loss of data when a button or the form is held by the mouse on the main form.
b) Quickly get the data from the event, stuff it in the queue, go back to sleep
c) Process data when we have it, otherwise sleep.

Can packages like AsyncoPro tie event handling to a non-main thread?

I've never done much with serial port event driven apps, most of what I've work with are polled and I want to do some testing.

Comment: AsyncPro is for serial port communications, not event handling. I'm confused about why you mentioned AsyncPro.

Comment: @Warren: I'm not personally familiar with the library, but if I were to guess, I'd say it probably uses event handlers (callbacks) as part of its interface.

Comment: I'm assuming the key is the events will stay on the thread the component is created on?  We are assuming a properly written non-visual component.

Comment: So you want to "transmit" an event from the main thread of Asyncpro to a background thread? It is safe to instantiate a non-visual control like AsyncPro, in a background thread, and run all its calls in that background thread. However, I believe in the case of AsyncPro, it will always fire its event handlers in the main thread, because it has been designed explicitly to do so. You should verify that assumption with a small test app.

Comment: @Warren: Yes that's the gist of it. The home grown library we use has done a good job until Unicode became the standard string. Moving to XE is a goal, but there are so many changes required I'm looking at starting over, and moving to an event driven interface from a polling one is very much top of mind.

Comment: Can I suggest you drop AsyncPro then, and replace it with TComPort, which is so simple and light that you can easily handle things as serial things SHOULD be handled, which is via a simple long-lived worker thread that handles all serial communications on a second thread context, and which then notifies the UI when data is available.  If you ask a question about SerialPort Worker Threads and them notifying the main thread, I can definitely help. [Are you sending UNICODE data over com ports?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do this, one way or another.  Not used Apro since D5 - the Apro I have does not work on my D2009, (unicode/string/ANSIstring issues),  & I have my own serial classes.  Most of the available serial components have the option of firing dataRx events on either the rx thread or the main GUI thread - obviously in your case you should select the rx thread, (Thread #2).  Shove the rx data into some buffer class and push it onto a producer-consumer thread to (Thread #3). Process it there.  If you need to do a GUI update from there, PostMessage the reference to the GUI thread and handle it in a user-defined message-handler procedure.

Done this sort of stuff loadsa times - it will work OK.

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: I guess my lack of knowledge is making sure the events fire on thread two. It probably is as simple as creating the components on thread #2 and that is where they will fire.

Comment: Apro, and most other serial port components, use an internal thread for reading from the port - this read thread is your thread #2. This read thread can usually be configured to either fire the read event directly or via the TThread.synchronize() mechanism, ie main GUI thread-safe by some boolean property.  It does not matter much which thread created the component. In your case, you could create the component in your GUI thread, (ie. plonk it on the form), but only activate it after creating thread #3.

Comment: IIRC: Apro contains explicit logic to ensure events fire on the primary thread!  So Rich, AsyncPro design is going to fight you. It was for exactly such reasons that I dropped AsyncPro years ago and I use either TComPort {by Dejan Crnila, and later continued by me} or a plain Win32 Serial Library in pascal.

Comment: Normally in our applications the data coming from a serial port is simple ASCII data from a bar code scanner. Outgoing data is ASCII to thermal transfer (label) printers. We generally talk directly to the printers via Ethernet or serial to be able to request status and to bypass the Windows spooler in high speed real-time situations. We do have slower labeling situations where we can use a Windows printer driver, but that is the exception.

I'll take a look at TComPort. Thanks.

Comment: @Warren P: it seem like you're right - I had to go back to D5 to check it, but Apro does not seem to have any option to fire events directly from the internal rx thread :(  I have used TComPort as well, but the one I had did not seem to work in D2009 & so, like you, I used my own lib.

Comment: There are even worse problems in AsyncPro, that eventually lead to me ditching it.

Comment: I picked this as my accepted answer because it came the closest to answering my specific question. I really do appreciate all of the input given in all of the answers.

Answer (score 6):

You can definitely tie event handling to a non-main thread.  What you can't do is tie screen updating to a non-main thread.  The Windows API is not threadsafe, and so the Delphi VCL, which is built on top of the Windows API, isn't either.  But your design is basically a good, workable idea; just remember to use the `Synchronize` or `Queue` methods of `TThread` to send any UI updates back to be executed on the main thread.

Comment: Many parts of the windows API are thread safe in one form or another. There's no single meaning of *thread safe*. Saying that something is or is not thread safe without stating precisely way you mean by the term is imprecise. To be precise concerning Windows GUI code, window handles have thread affinity. So all API calls which receive window handles must be made from the thread that created the window. From that single rule follows the rule that operations on VCL components should be performed from the main app thread.

Comment: @Mason AFAIK the Windows API *is* thread-safe, unless the contrary is documented in MSDN. In particular, all GDI, file, memory and conversion process is thread-safe since early version of Windows. It's even process-safe: you can e.g. send GDI messages from one process to another, without problem. The UI part of the VCL *is not* thread-safe, whereas most non-UI related part of the VCL *is* thread-safe.

Comment: @Mason - Good point. In my earlier days of doing threaded code I ran into issues modifying VCL components from the wrong thread.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest should be to define some [user messages](http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/delphi/howto_send_custom_window_message.htm), then sent it from sub-threads to the main thread.

It's perfectly thread-safe, and even process-safe.

Use `PostMessage()` with the Handle of the main form. But don't broadcast this `WM_USER+n` message to the whole UI, because you could confuse some part of the VCL which defines its own custom messages.

If you want to copy some textual data accross threads or processes, you can see `WM_COPY_DATA`. In practice, this is very fast, faster than named pipes for small messages.

For User Interface, I discovered than a stateless implementation is sometimes a good idea. That is, you don't call-back the main thread via a `Synchronize()` call or a GDI message, but your main GUI thread has a timer which check a shared memory buffer for pending updates. This is how the web works, and in practice, it's pretty easy to work with: you don't have to write any callback, each thread is independent, do its own stuff, and refresh when necessary.

But of course, the solution depends on your exact project architecture.

For a simple but proven library, see [AsyncCalls](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/), working from Delphi 5 up to XE. For latest versions of the IDE (Delphi 2007 and later), take a look at [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com/). By using such libraries, you'll ensure that your software implementation won't break anywhere: it's very common for a multi-threaded application to work as expected most of the time, then, for unknown reasons, going into an endless loop. And, of course, it happens only on the customer side, not yours... If you don't want to spend hours debugging your program, just trust those proven libraries, which are known to be well designed and debugged.

Comment: @Bouchez - I'll look into AsyncCalls. AsyncPro has been a workhorse here for about 10 years, but the fracturing and the lack of a real sponser looks difficult for using the Unicode strings. That is not a slam on the folks that have tried to maintain it.

I've used a threading library, ThreadNotify.pas, by Martin Harvey to make VCL updates on a thread easier, but I've seen a lot of praise for OTL.